# How do I disable clipboard functionality for an application in Windows

Tags: windows, security, clipboard

How do I disable clipboard functionality for an application in Windows? The reason for asking this question is to disallow users from copying any information for this application. The source code is not available for this application. Can i develop an application which doesn't allow the user to use copy function? Any example will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a clipboard monitoring program that would react to copies from FOO.EXE and wipe the clipboard.  Don't wipe everything, use the clipboard owner handle to identfy the app.  And don't wipe the clipboard during the notification event. Rather, set a short delay, such as sleep(500), to come back and clear it.  Also don't react to your own events, or you'll be in loop until you encounter the namesake of this forum (stack overflow).
Look for examples of clipboard monitoring in the language of your choice.

Comment: P.S. your users will hate this.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program which interrupts all key strokes and ignores ctrl+C (V,X?)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8

this is probably a good start

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.